# WP_query : Force last posts number over Reading Settings

Tags: wp-query

I need to display only the last 3 posts but i get 10 posts (Reading Settings).

Any idea ?

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h4>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h4>
            <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your loop, you must refer to `$wp_query` instance:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <?php the_excerpt();
    endwhile;
} else {
    echo 'No posts';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Also, `the_excerpt()` function takes one optional parameter, which is either `Post ID` or `$post` object. To control 'more' link, you use 'excerpt_more' filter.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. It keep showing 10 posts.

Comment: I've tested it. it works. Give me more info. Where did you use it? Did you get any errors. Check error_logs if any.